# Deleting a dynamic array of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stdvector, delete-operator

I believe this should be pretty simple and straightforward.  Why am I getting an error?
Here is the code:

```
std::vector<double> *myVectorArr;
myVectorArr = new std::vector<double>[10];
delete myVectorArr;
```

The error I get is:

```
munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why would I be getting this error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aside: Why not a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` or `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<double>[]>`?

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour.   Since you use an array-form of `new`, you need to use the array form of `delete`.   So do `delete [] myVectorArr`.    Better yet, use `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` and avoid the need for manually using `new` and `delete` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the operator delete [] instead of the operator delete

```
delete [] myVectorArr;
```